# Are there (still) no decent Pyramid OAuth2 Provider libraries?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, pyramid

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 on my server and am using Pyramid. I've come across several libraries written in Python, but many are either out of date (supports OAuth1), including the very misleadingly-named [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2). I'm new to OAuth (and Python/Pyramid), so the documentation would be nice or at the very least an example to work from. [This article](http://pydanny.com/the-sorry-state-of-python-oauth-providers.html) is over a year and a half old, yet the same issues persist. I came across [OAuthLib](https://github.com/idan/oauthlib), but the documentation for creating a provider is based on OAuth1 and I'm not sure how to integrate it with Pyramid. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [library called 'authomatic' on github](https://github.com/peterhudec/authomatic) that I've played with that so far seems to be pretty straightforward and easy to use. Prior to that I'd looked at another one called 'velruse' that also seemed to be pretty flexible. But for my needs now authomatic seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I love [the demo](http://authomatic-example.appspot.com).

Comment: Both look nice, but I only saw consumer OAuth2...I need to authorize people to authenticate on my server (unless I completely missed it in their docs)

Comment: @kristen - why did you accept this answer if it doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @TimTisdall you're right..I must have done that by accident

Comment: @kristen - did you ever find a solution for this?  Had you tried `pyramid_oauth2_provider`?

Comment: @TimTisdall I no longer use pyramid

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago, I had to implement Facebook/Google authentication in a web site, and I found it quite a mess until I found [velruze](https://github.com/bbangert/velruse). It works really fine and it's easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

I tried several oauth libraries.

The best I found (or the only one that really works for me) is [Authomatic](http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/index.html). I'm using it on a Pyramid site at Appengine.

Authomatic is framework agnostic. You can follow an example using authomatic with pyramid [here](http://peterhudec.github.io/authomatic/examples/pyramid-simple.html)

I had not lucky with Velruse. It uses 'requests' library, and it didn't work well in my sites. I had to hack it to use urllib3 directly for make it work.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong but I need to create an OAuth2 provider and neither Authomatic nor Velruse will do that. Both seem to be consumer only.

Comment: Excuse me, my mistake.